# Creating a graph in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, plot, graph, draw

I am trying to make a graph in Unity, based on the positions of some gameobjects stored in an array. This is my code so far. What does is moving the line renderer between 2 consecutive points, untill it reaches the last one. What I want to do is keep the previous line, create the new one and move it to the next point. Any idea how to achieve this ? Thanks a lot.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLine : MonoBehaviour {

private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
private LineRenderer[] lineRenderers;
private float counter;
private float dist;

private int i = 0;

public Transform origin;
public Transform destination;

public float lineDrawSpeed;

public GameObject[] Points;

void Start () 
{
    lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer> ();
    lineRenderers = new LineRenderer[40];

    lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.45f;
    lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.45f;
}

void Update()
{
    if (StockManager.isReady) 
    {
        Points = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Point");

        StartCoroutine (DrawTheLine ());

        StockManager.isReady = false;
    }
}

IEnumerator DrawTheLine()
{
    //lineRenderer.SetPosition (0, Points [0].transform.position);

    dist = Vector3.Distance (Points [0].transform.position, Points [1].transform.position);

    while (counter < dist && i < Points.Length - 1) 
    {
        lineRenderer.SetPosition (0, Points [i].transform.position);

        counter = Time.deltaTime * lineDrawSpeed;

        dist = Vector3.Distance (Points [i].transform.position, Points [++i].transform.position);

        float x = Mathf.Lerp (0, dist, counter);

        Vector3 pointA = Points [i].transform.position;
        Vector3 pointB = Points [i++].transform.position;

        Vector3 pointAlongLine = x * Vector3.Normalize (pointB - pointA) + pointA;

        lineRenderer.SetPosition (1, pointAlongLine);

        i--;

        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime (0.2f);
    }

    yield return null;
}
}
```

Comment: You already have an array of line renderers... You're using the same object over and over again, why not use the array?

Comment: @BrandonMiller sorry, that array is empty, I forgot to remove it from the code. I mean I tried using it, but I get a nullreference exception if I try to do : lineRenderers[i].SetPoisition in my DrawTheLine() method.

Comment: Before you call SetPosition make sure you do `lineRenderers[i] = new LineRenderer();` and you won't get an error.

Comment: @BrandonMiller I am getting a null refferece exception on the line you told me to write.

Comment: Is your graph 2d or 3d? I managed to draw 2d graphs with help of System.Drawing library. I used Image and Graphics classes to draw some lines, and then I converted System.Drawing.Image to Unity Texture2d. I also tested this library on Ubuntu, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I mislead you in the comments. LineRenderer is a component so simply doing `new LineRenderer()` will not do. It is expected to be added to a `GameObject`. Get rid of the array, you will not need it. The very first line of your while loop you may do `LineRenderer lineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();` and that should fix your problem. Your gameobject will come out with about 40 different LineRenderer components added to it. Keeping the array may be beneficial in the future, though, if you plan on accessing the LR's and manipulating them.